# Why does optimize,leastsq work and optimize.least_squares not?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, data-fitting, model-fitting

I'm trying to fit my experimental data to a theoretical model. I used to do it with scipy.optimize.leastsq, but sometimes I would get negative temperature.
Since I find no way to limit the parameter space using this function, I moved to using what I understood to be a newer version of the same thing, scipy.optimize.least_squares. However, with this function I never get a fit, even though they both fit the same expression.
Any idea why could that be and how to solve it?

```
p2 , success = sp.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(Voltage, Average),maxfev=800) #the fitting is minimizing said difference
p2 = sp.optimize.least_squares(errfunc, p0, args=(Voltage, Average),bounds=([0,0,-100,0,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,0],[0.005,np.inf,100,np.inf,np.inf,100,np.inf,0.005]),max_nfev=800) #the fitting is minimizing said difference
```

Comment: As a general practice, I suggest using None instead of infinities (np.inf, or -np.inf) when not bounding a variable. This can only make numerics more stable.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "never get a fit"? Could it be the case that `least_squares` does minimize the error best it could within your provided bounds, but `leastsq` is allowed to find "impossible solutions" out of bounds with even lower error values?

Comment: @Learning-is-a-mess How do you correctly use "None"? I tried to put it instead of np.inf and I get the error "ValueError: `x0` is infeasible."

Comment: @mimocha only some of the times. The reason I think there is an issue with the fitting itself is that some fits I can fit within the bounds with 'leastsq' and 'least_squares' cannot find a fit

Comment: Can you share the objective function as well as the p0 value?

Comment: Fitting with bounds is very different to fitting without bounds. If you only want a parameter `a` to be positive, fit `a**2` instead.

Comment: btw, it's `x0` not `p0`, right?

Comment: 'p0' and 'x0' are the same, it just gets a different name inside the 'least_squares' function.

Comment: The objective function is an integral over: '(abs((((1 / ((x - Voltage - p[6] * 1j) ** 2 - (p[0]) ** 2) - ((x - Voltage) * (2 * (x - Voltage) - 2 * p[6] * 1j)) / ((x - Voltage - p[6] * 1j) ** 2 - (p[0]) ** 2)) ** 2) * ((1 / (np.exp((x) / (k * p[1])) + 1)) - (1 / (np.exp((x - Voltage) / (k * [1])) + 1))) - (((((x - Voltage) / (((x - Voltage - p[6] * 1j)) ** 2 - (p[0]) ** 2) ** 0.5))) * (1 / (k * [1]) * np.exp((x - Voltage) / (k * p[1]))) / (np.exp((x - Voltage) / (k * p[1])) + 1) ** 2)) * ((x) / ((x - p[6] * 1j)) ** 2 - (p[7]) ** 2) ** 0.5)))'